# Wrong backbone collection length. Can't each this collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections

Sorry for my bad English. Tell me why the following happens:

I have some backbone collection:

```
var Background = window.Models.Background = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var Backgrounds = window.Models.Backgrounds = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: window.Models.Background,

    url: '/backgrounds/',

    initialize: function() {

        this.fetch({
            success: this.fetchSuccess(this),
            error: this.fetchError
        });
    },

    fetchSuccess: function( collect_model ) {
        new BackgroundsView ({ collection : collect_model });
    },

    fetchError: function() {
        throw new Error("Error fetching backgrounds");
    }

});
```

And some view:

```
var BackgroundsView = window.Views.BackgroundsView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'div',

    className: 'hor_slider',

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        console.log(this.collection);
        this.collection.each( function (background) {
            console.log(background);
            //var backgroundView = new BackgroundView ({ model: background });
            //this.$el.append(backgroundView.render().el);
        });
    }

});
```

now i creating collection

```
var backgrounds = new Models.Backgrounds();
```

but when I must render this view, in the process of sorting the collection its length is 0, but should be two. [This log I see at console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yijxl.png). How is this possible? What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Why not making it more simple? setup a listener in the view, that listens to the collection changes, and for every change it re-renders the view.

Comment: @MorKadosh, I tried to do so as you say. But I need to create a "view" immediately after the initialization of the collection. But in fact, "fetch" occurs at the end of code execution. At the time of the call "fetchSuccess" collection is still not ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the view before the collection fetch is successfull. Your code should be:

```
initialize: function() {

    this.fetch({
        success: this.fetchSuccess,
        //------------------------^ do not invoke manually
        error: this.fetchError
    });
},
fetchSuccess: function(collection, response) {
    new BackgroundsView ({ collection : collection});
},
```

You should let backbone call `fetchSuccess` when the fetch succeeds. Right now you're invoking the funcion immediately and passing the return value `undefined` as success callback.

---

This looks like a wrong pattern. Your data models shouldn't be aware of/controlling the presentation logic.

You have a view floating around without any reference to it. You should be creating a view instance  with reference(for example from a router, or whatever is kick starting your application) and passing the collection to it. Then fetch the collection from it's initialize method and render after the fetch succeeds. Collection can be referenced via `this.collection` inside view.

Alternatively you can fetch the collection from router itself and then create view instance. Either way collection/model shouldn't be controlling views.

Comment: Thank you! Granted, it was a really bad decision. After tracing the script, I realized that fetch takes place much later than I had wanted. I added the option "reset" to fetch and attached to the event handler in the view. Collection and view must be created individually. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is structured in the following way, the problem is solved. It was necessary to add a parameter reset to fetch.

```
var Background = window.Models.Background = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var Backgrounds = window.Models.Backgrounds = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: window.Models.Background,

    url: '/backgrounds/',

    initialize: function() {

        this.fetch({
            reset : true,
        });
    }

});

var BackgroundsView = window.Views.BackgroundsView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'div',

    className: 'hor_slider',

    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
    },

    render: function() {

        this.collection.each( function (background) {

            var backgroundView = new BackgroundView ({ model: background });
            this.$el.append(backgroundView.render().el);

        }, this); 
        $('#view_list').empty();
        $('#view_list').append(this.$el);

        return this;

    }

});
```